# CKEditor force root node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, nodes

Is there a way to force a root node into a CKEditor instance?
I would want anything the user types to go in between the tags of the node.

The node should be formatted:

```
<div class="text-block">
</div>
```

Thank you

Edit:
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource describes HTML which must NOT be editable in an instance. 
However, `CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push( /<div\\\sclass="text-block">*?<\\\/div>/gi );` does not prevent the html from changing.

Comment: Why not do this when the markup is outputted? No sense storing this if it's always the same.

Comment: I need all text to be wrapped in the div. Regardless of any changes in the editor. This is impossible currently because CKEditor allows users to paste over or erase content in the text area. Users will not have access to view source to add the div and even if they did, this is unacceptable since they know nothing about HTML

Comment: To further illustrate what I am going for here, see this link: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block which details how tinymce does it. Unfortunately, I cannot use tinymce but this is the exact behavior I need; a root block that always is the same...no matter what the user does in the editor.

Comment: So, start off with the wrapper in place, and check if it's still there when submitted. If not, wrap it again. Perhaps explain the purpose of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor allows developers to set a class on its body tag, resident only during instance loads: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.bodyClass